# Square root of a function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_0a_1,a_2,\dots ,a_n$ are $n$ real numbers and define a function $f:[0,2 \pi] \rightarrow \mathcal{R}$ as :
$$ f(x)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n}a_ia_j\cos(j-k)x$$.One can easily show that $f$ is nonnegative on the given domain.Now define a function $g$ on the same domain
as under
$$ g(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$$My question is: is $g$a function of bounded variation on the given domain?

**My attempt:**
$f$ is obviously a function of bounded variation,NY the algebra of linear sum of functions bounded variation.  By a property of functions
of bounded variation ,we know if a function $h(x)$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$, then
$$ V(h;a,b)=\int_a^b|h'(x)|dx$$
Applying the same to the function $$g(x)=\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=0}^{n}a_ia_j\cos(j-i)x}$$,we have:
$$ |g'(x)|=\frac{\big|\sum_{i,j=0}^{n}a_ia_j (j-i)\sin(j-i)x\big|}{2\sqrt{\sum_{i,j=0}^{n}a_ia_j\cos(j-i)x}} $$

So now,if we can somehow  show that $\int_0^{2 \pi}|g('x)|dx $ is bounded( *we may impose appropriate conditions on f to that end, for example* $f(x) \neq 0) \forall x \in [0,2 \pi]$,it willbe established that g is of bounded variation. Is  it possible in that case to find some bound for the total variation  of  $g$ on thegiven domain? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$| \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_je^{ijx}|^{2}=\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^{n} a_ja_ke^{i(j-k)x}$. Take real parts on both sides. Conclude that $g(x)$ is nothing but $| \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_je^{ijx}|$. Now $|g(x)-g(y)| \leq | \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} a_j(e^{ijx}-e^{iky})|$. Use the inequalty $|e^{it}-e^{is}| \leq |t-s|$ to finish.

Comment: Thank you for the help.what about my approach using inegral and the question of bound on the total variation?

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to see how your argument can be completed. @sajjadveeri

Comment: My confusion is  a general point and can be seen apart from my question and that is :if g'(x) takes infinite values at finite number of points in the domain (i.e. where the denominator vanishes),can we somehow still rescue \int^0^{2 \pi}|g'(x)|

Comment: It is possible for an integrable function to take infinite values at a  finite number of points. For example. $f(x)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \frac 1 {\sqrt {|x-c_i|}}$ is such a function. @sajjadveeri